# WPF Programmatically add DataGridTextColumn with DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatrigger, programmatically-created

I have a `DataGrid` that is made of dynamically by the user.  That means each time it runs the columns could and will be very different.  Each column is programmatically added for that reason.  I need to add some `DataTriggers` to it so figured this would work:

```
Style style = new Style();
style.TargetType = typeof(DataGridTextColumn);
DataTrigger tg = new DataTrigger()
{
    Binding = new Binding(value),
    Value = "bad data"
};
tg.Setters.Add(new Setter()
{
    Property = UIElement.VisibilityProperty,
    Value = Visibility.Hidden
});
```

While this gives no errors in the IDE when run it crashes and gives me 
`'DataGridTextColumn' type must derive from FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement.`

What is the correct way of adding a `DataTrigger` to a `DataGridTextColumn` Programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `typeof(DataGridCell)`. The trigger should be applied to the `Cell` itself, not the `Column`.